# Error in HR.Rates$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, rstudio

Hope someone can help,

I am working my way through "Analysing Baseball Data With R" by Max Marchi and Jim Albert however on page 45 in reference to saving a dataset I get the error:

```
Error in HR.Rates$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

This error is in response to the code:

```
Mantle <- cbind(Age, HR, AB, Rates=HR.Rates$y)
```

How can I resolve this?
I am only just getting to grips with R and this book was making it easy until this happened.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, do you have a variable named `HR.Rates`? What is `class(HR.Rates)`? It sounds like you're treating it as a data.frame/list when it isn't. You might want to verify you created the object correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, class(HR.Rates) returns:
{[1] "numeric"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from a google book search, you should have defined

```
hr.rates <- function(age, hr, ab) {
    rates <- round(100*hr/ab,1)
    list(x=age, y=rates)
}
```

and the code you should be running is

```
HR <- c(13,23,21,27,37,52,34,42,31,40,54)
AB <- c(341,549,461,543,517,533,474,519,541,527,514)
Age <- 19:29
HR.Rates <- hr.rates(Age, HR, AB)
Mantle <- cbind(Age, HR, AB, Rates=HR.Rates$y)
```

which works just fine. You probably have a mistake in either the definition of `hr.rates` or you invoked it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my problem.
Entering it as a script copy + paste, I have looked back over my code but still can't see my mistake.
I will have to be more careful in future.